# Array Out of Bounds issue

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a very simple program with one textbox, and a button.

The user is told to put the name of two colors in the box, separated by a space.

For example "red green"
The output will print on the screen, "The apple is red with green dots.".

However I need it to function when there is only one word entered on the screen. I am using an array holding the split strings. When I only type in red, I get this error.

"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

***Here is the code:***

```
String userInput = textField.getText();
String[] userInputSplit = userInput.split(" ");
String wordOne = userInputSplit[0];
String wordTwo = userInputSplit[1];
if (wordTwo !=null){
                System.out.println("The apple is " + wordOne + " with " + wordTwo + " dots.");
                } else {
                 System.out.println("The apple is " + wordOne + " with no colored dots.");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just do something easy like this:

```
String wordOne = userInputSplit[0];
String wordTwo = null;
if (userInputSplit.length > 1){
    //This line will throw an error if you try to access something 
    //outside the bounds of the array
    wordTwo = userInputSplit[1];  
}
if (wordTwo !=null) {
    System.out.println("The apple is " + wordOne + " with " + wordTwo + " dots.");
} 
else {
    System.out.println("The apple is " + wordOne + " with no colored dots.");
}
```

Comment: I'd use `String wordTwo = userInputSplit.length > 1 ? userInputSplit[1] : null;`, I find that easier to parse, but that's just me.

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah that would be cleaner, but since this question is pretty basic I'm thinking using the conditional operator would just add more confusion to the OP.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What's the issue?  I don't see anything wrong with it, but I don't have a compiler in front of me at the moment.

Comment: This works great. If I wanted to add a third color, do I change "if (userInputSplit.length > 1)" to > 2?

Comment: @DanielFischer It does now, it didn't before the update. The declaration `String wordTwo = userInputSplit[1]` within the `if (userInputSplit.length > 1)` statement wasn't going to compile, has been updated to correct for it ;)

Comment: @user1828096 just don't try to access something in an array unless you know it is at least that big

Comment: @MadProgrammer You should have refreshed. That was fixed pretty immediately. It was already corrected when I posted my (then deleted) "won't compile".

Comment: @DanielFischer That's a fair point, but I'd spend my life refreshing ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Besides, I wasn't a criticism, just a nudge ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's fine, but in this case the author nudged himself faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could enclose your print logic with a guard `if` statement:

```
if (userInputSplit.length > 1) {
  String wordOne = userInputSplit[0];
  String wordTwo = userInputSplit[1];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This worked along with the response from KDiTraglia.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a pre-condition check to see if the input from the user contains any spaces...

```
String userInput = textField.getText();
userInput = userInput.trim(); // Remove any leading/trailing spaces
if (userInput != null && userInput.length() > 0) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(64);
    if (userInput.contains(" ")) {
        String[] userInputSplit = userInput.split(" ");
        String wordOne = userInputSplit[0];
        String wordTwo = userInputSplit[1];
        msg.append("The apple is ").append(wordOne);
        msg.append(" with ").append(wordTwo).append(" dots");
    } else {
        msg.append("The apple is ").append(userInput).append(" with no colored dots.");
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
} else {
    // No input condition...
}
```

That's just another way of looking at the problem...

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually learned something from your snippet, and can use this for something similar.